# Saving a String in MongoDB as a date saves wrong values

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

**I am trying to save a string in MongoDB as a date but having hard times for storing the right values.**

In Mongoose schema data value is stored as Date, however, I pass the value to data as `new Date("MM-dd-YYYY")` but when I look up in the database the value is transformed to this format `ISODate("YYYY-MM-dd-1T21:00:00Z")`

The format wouldn't bother me if the date would be the same but as you notice the value in the database is one day earlier then the value which I want to be.

So instead of `2018-09-20` is `2018-08-19`. My guess is that default UTC time is not the same or something like that but how can I set the correct UTC time?

Edit:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose')
var dateformat =require('moment');

//Schema
var ReservationSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
name : {
    type:String,
required : true,
},

numberOfGuests : {
    type : Number ,
required : true,}
,
email: {
    type : String,
    required:true,
    },
phone: {
        type : String,
        required:true,
        },
data:{
    type:Date,
    require:true,
},
timetables:{
    type:String,
    require:true,
},
furtherRequests: {
    type : String,
    }

});

var reservvar = module.exports = mongoose.model('Rezervari', ReservationSchema ,'Rezervari');

module.exports.createReservation = function (query,callback){
//query.data = dateformat.utc(query.data).format("MM-DD-YYYY")
reservvar.create(query,callback); 

}
module.exports.getReservations = function (callback){
reservvar.find({},callback); 

}
```

Index.js file :

```
app.get('/api/reservations',function(req,res) {
Rezervari.getReservations(function(err,reserv){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    var changetime = reserv[1].data;
    console.log(reserv[1].data)
    changetime = dateformat.utc(changetime).format("MM-DD-YYYY") // this one returns the date in desired format but with wrong values as stored in db
    console.log(changetime)
    res.json(reserv);
});
});
app.post('/api/createrezervare', function (req,res) {
const reserv = req.body
const name = reserv.name
const numberofg = reserv.number
const phone = reserv.phone
const email = reserv.email
const data = reserv.date
const timetable = reserv.time
const furtreq = reserv.frequests
Rezervari.createReservation({name:name,numberOfGuests:numberofg,phone:phone,email:email,data:data,timetables:timetable,furtRequests:furtreq},function(err,reserv){
if(err){
    throw err}
res.json({status:true})
})
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are inserting a Javascript Date Object from Node.js, and that same Date is being inserted in MongoDB, it's being inserted correctly.

I think you are confusing how dates are stored internally and how are they formatted when you print them.

When you check the content of your data in MongoDB it's just shown in that particular format, an ISO date. If you take a close look at the date shown you can see a **Z** a the end, Z means "zero hour offset" also known as "Zulu time" (UTC).

In Javascript when you create a Date object without setting the timezone, it's by default created in your system timezone. Also, Date objects are not stored with any format, nor in JS nor in MongoDB. In JS, dates are stored internally as time values (milliseconds since 1970-01-01).

Supposing we are in Japan, JST time (UTC+9):

```
const d = new Date("09-20-2018");
console.log(d.getTime()); // 1537369200000
console.log(d.toString()); // Thu Sep 20 2018 00:00:00 GMT+0900 (JST)
console.log(d.toISOString()); // 2018-09-19T15:00:00.000Z
```

First we are printing out the number of ms, after the Date including the timezone, and finally the ISO Date, almost same format that MongoDB uses to print dates in the Mongo shell (anyway, in UTC).

So, `new Date("09-20-2018")` is going to store the milliseconds until 09-20-2018 00:00 in Japan Time. Then, if you insert that object in MongoDB, internally it will store the correct date (I don't know internal details of MongoDB, but maybe it's storing the milliseconds as well).

If you check MongoDB you will see something like `ISODate("2018-09-19T15:00:00Z")`.

Comment: Yes but date is different , I gave you an example. Or you mean that the value of the date if I extract from mongo will still be the correct value?

Comment: I expanded the explanation. MongoDB is just showing in the shell the date in UTC time, but it should be correct. If you convert the date MongoDB is printing (in UTC) to your local time it should match.

Comment: So the only way is to format the date when I am trying to retrieve date values from db?

Comment: I am showing those records in a table on a webpage, can't it just be like  2018-09-19T15:00:00.000Z so I am trying to format to a more familiar date type

Comment: @GabrielCostin  true, you don't have to look at the insides of the mongodb and how it stores DateTime values. When you write your GET method with your own format it will receive the correct date.

Comment: In that case you can format the date you get from MongoDB to your desired format in your front side. You can do it natively using [Date.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/prototype) methods, but I recommend a library like moment.js to do it easier.

Comment: @RamanHaivaronski Ok but for exemple I know how to format date but the problem is if the date is 2018-08-09 in MongoDB then the correct value would be 2018-08-10 but when I format date I will get 2018-08-09 so that is not right, isn't there any way to specify time zone when creating a date?

Comment: @GabrielCostin I would recommend you convert the date to UTC and then save it to MongoDB, while retrieving you can change it back to your timezone. Use library like moment.js to easily convert to UTC

Comment: @Royson I don't think that's going to help, the date stored in MongoDB is going to be exactly the same.

Comment: @Royson I am already using moment.js for converting date,  could you give an exemple of how to convert date to UTC please?

Comment: @GabrielCostin the date is correct even if it says `2018-08-09` in MongoDB, it's just in UTC. It's a different day because I guess you are in a timezone that sums hours +1, +2, etc; so when some hours are rested to be printed in UTC of course the day is changing as well. When you get your data back from MongoDB you get a Date object, right? Just format that Date object to your desired format :)

Comment: @GabrielCostin check this link to parse to UTC: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/

Comment: @AntonioVal Ok but how to specify time zones when converting the date?

Comment: It depends on the format you want to convert the Date object to a string. By default, moment.js parses and displays in local time. So you can just do something like this: `moment(dateObject).format('MM-DD-YYYY')`

Comment: @AntonioVal I am doing exactly the same however it does not update to current utc(my time is gmt+3) so instead of 2018-08-17 I still have 2018-08-16(just an example)

Comment: Something must be wrong in your implementation I think. It would be helpful if you edit your question showing us how are you inserting the date and how are you getting it.

Comment: @Royson I tried what you recommended too but it is not working.It throws me an exception saying that date format is not in ISO date format

Comment: `.utc()` is not necessary. Try this: `changetime = dateformat(changetime).format("MM-DD-YYYY")`

Comment: @AntonioVal Oh somehow this one works great, now I have a different problem that new value  of the data object is not saving into the array

Comment: I'm glad it's working :). If my answer was useful please accept and upvote it.

Comment: I think you can open a new question for the array problem, since it's not related to dates.

Comment: @AntonioVal Ok there you go